# Find the content of a TextBox inside a DataTemplate with multiple rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have this code:

```
<StackPanel>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Position}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="5" />
                <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="X" Click="Delete" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For example i have 3 rows. I want to delete the second row with it's elements. I click the `Delete` Button in the second Row and all i need is the `ID` inside the TextBox. If i get the `ID` in the code behind i can delete that Position from the Database. There is no problem if i have only one Row. In that case i give a name for the TextBox containing the `ID` and i can get the value in code behind. But how can i do this if i have 3,4,10 Positions each of them in a separate Row?

Comment: Don't use `Click` event but bind a `Command` to your view model, like you bind `ID` and `Name`, and deal with it there

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864502/using-events-and-commands-within-itemscontrol-in-wpf) question addresses very similar problem

Comment: Modify the Datamodel not the datatemplate content if you do it properly UI will reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may bind the Button's `Tag` to the `ID` property and access that in the `Click` handler:

```
<Button Grid.Column="4" Content="X" Click="Delete" Tag="{Binding ID}" />
```

Click handler:

```
private void Delete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var id = (int)button.Tag;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I made only a small change. Since `ID` returns `int` i converted the tag in `int` not `string`

Comment: That was what I wrote initially, then I thought the ID may be a string :-) I've updated the answer.